# Damaging effects from water in pre-ground coffee container/funnel DeLonghi ecam550.65sb?

Tags: maintenance, water

A relative of mine accidentally poured water into the pre-ground coffee hole/funnel. Is there a risk of things getting damaged? I know someone has asked this question for a Magnifica S, but I have a ecam550.65sb which might have different effects. It took a few days to notice this as the relative did not mention anything and when I was about to empty the container for the coffee grounds it was filled with water.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have not got any experience on this machine, but very probably no harm occurred.

In most automatic machines pre-ground funnel is a shortcut to the tamping mechanism. So, the coffee put in the funnel directly goes on top of the mechanism, tamped, then boiling water is directed onto it.

If this is the case, all of the water just passes through the heat-resistant mechanism and fills in the reservoir.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! I really do hope so. I am one of those people where I would not have noticed a thing unless I knew about it.